# Node js express view engine

Tags: node.js, express, viewengine

I recently started node.js and express and I just couldn't find what is this view engine. and what's the difference between different kinds of them. for example : `app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Comment: this engine keyword is not for extension ,, this is an keyword like jade and ejs to render pages script

Answer (score 0):

```
app.set('view engine', 'html'); // Means, render pages in HTML
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); // Means, render pages in Jade template
```

`view engine` is just a keyword/property to tell/set ExpressJS what kind of engine/format to render the page in.

What's `Jade`? [Go here](http://jade-lang.com/)